BibLaTex - Reference format for multiple ISSNs (print + digital)
What is the best / standard approach to creating a bibilography entry for a journal with print and digital editions (with an ISSN, and eISSN number, respectively). Should I create a new field for eISSN, or should I override the ISSN field as a list?

Before I'd do anything here I would double-check if two ISSNs (or even one) are really necessary and useful here. I can imagine that there are some situations where you'd want them, but in "normal bibliographies" you probably mainly cite articles and not the whole journal, in which case something like the DOI is much more useful than the ISSN.

That said. I don't think there is a standard approach the issn field (like the similar isbn field) canonically only accepts a single value. If you need two ISSNs both the approach of defining a separate field for the eISSN and changing the type of the issn field to a list seem appropriate. I'd probably prefer the latter, since I don't really see why the ISSN of the electronic version - as opposed to the print version - of the journal should go into the new field. The list is more symmetrical on the data input level. Of course if you want the output to reflect eISSN vs ISSN it's different
